# Getting TypeError when running script with os.path.join()

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have the following lines in a script I am running:

```
api_xml = os.path.join(opts.out, os.path.basename(
    opts.api_raw).replace('.raw', '.xml'))
```

Running with Python 3.7, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_code.py", line 32, in <module>
    opts.api_raw).replace('.raw', '.xml'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 146, in basename
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

It seems to me like a simple join and then replace, not sure why it is failing.

Comment: What are the  values of `opts.out` and `opts.api_raw`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

means that you passed `None` to a function that expects a path.

Try adding these lines before you try to build `api_xml`:

```
assert opts.out is not None
assert opts.api_raw is not None
```